# Get Id and Label of Selected Item

Tags: jsf

I have an SelectItem Object array

```
SelectItem[] list;

<h:selectOneMenu value="#{Bean.id}">                        
    <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.list}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

i can get id but how can i get label...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item label won't be sent as request parameter, only the item value. This is by HTML specification. But you don't need to get it from the request at all. You have it **already** in your `list` in the backing bean. If you make it a `Map<K, V>` instead of `SelectItem[]`, then you should easily be able to get the label associated with the selected value.

```
String label = map.get(value);
// ...
```

In JSF 2.x / EL 2.2 you can use `Map<K, V>` in the `<f:selectItems>`, but if you're still on the old JSF 1.x, then you should bake another `SelectItem[]` or `List<SelectItem>` based on that map.